# rust mio always reports even on stdin

Tags: linux, rust, epoll

I tried adding a few fds to mio, including the stdin.
My application gets stuck trying to read from stdin, after I get an event from mio, that stdin is readable.

When I straced the application, I noticed, that mio uses the `epoll_wait` and that that syscall returns instantly.

```
strace -e trace=epoll_create,epoll_ctl,epoll_wait,read,epoll_create1 ./target/debug/ongybar

epoll_create1(EPOLL_CLOEXEC)            = 6
epoll_ctl(6, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 7, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLET, {u32=4294967295, u64=18446744073709551615}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(6, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {EPOLLIN, {u32=0, u64=0}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(6, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 0, {EPOLLIN, {u32=0, u64=0}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(6, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 4, {EPOLLIN, {u32=4, u64=4}}) = 0
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=4, u64=4}}], 4, -1) = 1
read(4, "[...], 8192) = 1004
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=0, u64=0}}], 4, -1) = 1
read(0,
```

The full code I am experiencing this with is on [github](https://github.com/Ongy/ongybar/tree/SO_mio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strong guess is, that not fd 0 (stdin) but fd 3 became readable:
Here

```
epoll_ctl(6, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {EPOLLIN, {u32=0, u64=0}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(6, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 0, {EPOLLIN, {u32=0, u64=0}}) = 0
```

you can see, that fd 0 and 3 are *both* registered with epoll_data u32/u64 = 0.

And here

```
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=0, u64=0}}], 4, -1) = 1
```

you can only deduce, that one of the two registered file descriptors with u32/u64=0 are readable now, but you cannot distinguish between fd 0 and fd 3 here! And since reading from stdin blocks it has to be fd 3.

The solution is to use a unique identifier for u32/u64 for each file descriptor to be properly able to identify the correct file descriptor which had activity.